# Is there an easier way to execute 'Wrap every parameter -> Indent all parameters'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, key-bindings, visual-studio-2022

Say I have the following method

```
public Task HandleAsync(ActivityCreated domainEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

But I wish to reformat it like this (indent all parameters):

```
public Task HandleAsync(
    ActivityCreated domainEvent, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

I know I can move my cursor to any of the param names and enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to select the option:

[image]

But is there an easier way to do this, like a shortcut which will immediately do this for the current method I'm in?

I searched for 'indent' in key mappings but nothing interesting really appears:

[image]

Or perhaps there is some other trick to do it more quickly? For example if I auto-implement an interface with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> is there some way of telling VS to wrap and indent those method params each time? Currently they always appear in line

Generally speaking I only wish to do this on lines exceeding ~115 characters

Comment: After discussion, it is very difficult for us to fulfill your request, we suggest you go to DC to submit a Request.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Thanks for the comment Jiale - what do you mean by DC?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8

Comment: I opened a request here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/An-easier-way-to-execute-Wrap-every-par/1667626?space=8&q=Wrap+every+parameter+-%3E+Indent+all+parameters